# Counter int is incremented without asking

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

Consider this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char *task = "foo";

  int key = 0;
  int arr[] = {};

  if (!strcmp(task, "foo")) {
    key++;
  }

  arr[key] = 2;

  key++;

  printf("key: %d\n", key);
}
```

The final value of `key` is `3`. It should be `2`.

If I change `"foo"` to `"foo1"` on the first occurrence, the final value of `key` is `1`, as expected.

If I change `arr[key] = 2` to `arr[key] = 1`, or remove that line, the final value of `key` is `2`, as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: `int arr[] = {};` that's not valid C++.

Comment: Why doesn't g++ complain then?

Comment: @juanchopanza Why not? Initialiser list.

Comment: it compiles for me using g++ test.cpp -o test

Comment: [0-length arrays are a gcc extension.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

Comment: @BoBTFish zero length automatic storage arrays aren't valid C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza The question is specifically tagged `g++`. So yes, not valid C++, but valid in the context of this question.

Comment: @BoBTFish I didn't say it was invalid g++. I can guarantee OP didn't know this is a g++ extension. It is useful information for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

`int arr[] = {};` you are trying to tell compiler to allocate memory for array of size which is equal to elements specified in between `{}`. But since you have no elements, compiler didn't allocate any memory. All this is happening at compile time.

And then you are trying `arr[key] = 2;`, that you are trying to modify the memory which you don't own. In this case, you will either get segmentation fault, or code will silently move on and corrupt memory allocated which is allocated somewhere else by your code.

so ideally you should have some elements in between `{}`, if you know at compile time that you will never need more than that, or use dynamic allocation at run time.

Comment: This seems like the most explanatory answer. I fixed my problem by using some logic to find out how big the array would have to be, and declaring it without initialising any values.

Answer (score 6):

You have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code so anything can happen.

```
int arr[] = {};
```

is a zero sized array which is not standard.  Since its size is 0 accessing any element and setting its value is undefined behavior.  Since we now have undefined behavior there is no longer any way to reason out how the program works.

Comment: Why does g++ issue no warnings or errors regarding this undefined behaviour?

Comment: @srynznfyra Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior in almost all cases

Comment: @srynznfyra It doesn't have to. You broke it. In general, working out if an array index is out of bounds is not possible at compile time. (The index may come from elsewhere).

Comment: @srynznfyra If you tun up the warnings you should have at least seen you were using a 0 sized array: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9ae85778ed90c0

Answer (score 1):

This is *undefined behavior*, so it might produce different results on a different compiler or for any of a number of reasons.

The array you define has zero length. The standard *might* enforce a minimum of length 1, but in this case it doesn't matter - you're accessing `[1]` which is out of bounds either way. That's what causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that the question is specifically tagged `g++`, so the 0-length array is fine. The out-of-bounds access is still UB of course.

Comment: @BoBTFish I know that the C++ standard enforces a minimum object size of 1, even if the object is empty, but I don't know how that applies to an array. That's why I used the wishy-washy language. I didn't mean to imply that you couldn't *declare* an array of length 0.